# R `cor()` style results but with `Kendall's W`

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataframe and want to calculate Kendall's W for each pair of variables.

This function `kendall(df, correct = TRUE)` calculates the W for the entire dataframe. I would like a table more like `cor(df, method=c("kendall"))` which compares every pair of variables, however that function uses Kendall's tau and not Kendall's W.

I would like to do this calculation:

```
install.packages("irr")
library(irr)
df<-iris
kendall(df[,1:4], correct=TRUE)
```

In this way:

```
cor(df[,1:4])
```

Comment: Please use the package name and a small reproducible example

Comment: @akrun - added a brief example. Hope that helps

Comment: @akrun - that's Kendall's tau and not Kendall's W. Same problem as using `corr(df, method="Kendall")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether I understand it correctly, is the code below helpful?

```
my.kendall <- function(df) {
  func<-Vectorize(function(i,j){kendall(df[,c(i,j)])$value})
  outer(X=1:ncol(df), Y=1:ncol(df), FUN=func)
}
```